# Message: element not interactable on accessing a tag python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to access the sign in button on the url as shown in the code below. I have verified the content of the url as well as the href. They are both consistent with what appears using inspect element dev tool.

But on clicking the extracted element I get the error:

```
Message: element not interactable
```

I have no idea why is this occurring.

Kindly help me solve this issue

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# setup the browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
browser.get('https://libraries.usc.edu/')
browser.maximize_window()

# access the relevant a tag after inspecting it in dev tool inspect element
a_tag_elt = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(lambda browser :
                                             browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.site-header__signin a'))

# sanity check by printing out the details
print(type(a_tag_elt))
print(a_tag_elt.get_attribute('href'), a_tag_elt.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

# produces Message: element not interactable error
a_tag_elt.click()

# quit the browser
browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Sign In** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.main-navigation__navbar span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='main-navigation__navbar ']//span"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 2):

To click on Sign In link Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following css selector.

```
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.main-navigation__navbar>.main-navigation__navbar-text"))).click()
```

Or following xpath.

```
WebDriverWait(browser,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='Sign In']"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```